# SSO facebook connect plugin failure on login - cordova

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

Ok, I have scoured all four corners of the net... twice... and have yet found and answer to something which I think must be a piece of piss to figure yet nothing I have tried has worked. This problem seems to have popped up all over the internet but apps are still being developed with faceboook integration so why is it I cannot find a flipping answer!!

Anyways, I'm going to write down everything I have done.

1. Downloaded latest cordova and setup a project.
2. Downloaded the facebook connect plugin for cordova/phonegap and added in the hackbook to my project
3. Downloaded the Latest Java SDK
4. Setup A separate Facebook SDK project
5. Included the separate project into my project which requires facebook login auth.
6. added the ConnectPlugin.java file in and included the plugin call in the config.xml plugin project.
7. Loged into facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ set myself up an app.
8. Gave it a temp name, and whipped in some basic info.
9. Went down to Native Android App, put in package name (org.apache.cordova.name) and class ( org.apache.cordova.name.main) and also made sure "facebook login" was set to enabled.
10. Downloaded openSSL (the one that everyone says to download (im on win8))
11. opened up command prompt, navigated to c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin and ran

**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64**

I copied the debug keystore fron the android sdk folder and put it a shorter path dir because im lazy.

1. entered my password when asked for.
2. copied the keystore something like this **Bmce+9aHdOoVtE7fS3F07tfj7Bc=** and entered in the app details in facebook android native app details.
3. Hit F5 on my project, gave it a clean and ran it through the Android Virtual Device.

**Wola! works like a beauty**

1. closed down the AVD, pluged in my SGS3, hit run.
2. click login, and displays **"cordovaExample would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address"**
3. hit "ok"
4. The app crashes, dies and blew up a small donkey.

Can anyone tell me what the hell im doing wrong. I know the SSO has problems, thats why it works on the AVD because facebook isnt installed on it but I have created the stupid hash keys!!!

Anyone, I beg you, Mr Facebook if you are out there, what am I doing wrong!!!

Thank you!

**edit**

Forgot to add the log:

```
D/PluginManager(16868):     init()
D/CordovaWebView(16868):    >>> loadUrlNow()
D/DroidGap(16868):          Incoming Result
D/DroidGap(16868):          Request code = 64206
D/DroidGap(16868):          We have a callback to send this result to
D/AndroidRuntime(16868):    Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(16868):          threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4111e2a0)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.apache.cordova.main/org.apache.cordova.main.main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {org.apache.cordova.main/org.apache.cordova.main.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {org.apache.cordova.main/org.apache.cordova.main.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3182)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    ... 12 more
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:849)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
E/AndroidRuntime(16868):    ... 13 more
I/GATE(16868):              <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I never... found the answer here: [java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo while logging using Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611969/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfo-while-logging-u)

appears that I had "Don't keep activities" checked in the developer options which oooobbbvioulsy would cause this....

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood, the key that you generated only works on a virtual device. To run your application in real phone, you must upload your application to "google play" where you provide a signed code that will allow you to connect the application to facebook from a real phone.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: I have exported as apk, uploaded directly from my machine to phone and regenerated a key but i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get your "sign app key" using this program http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download/keyhash.zip

Install this program on your android development environment and run the application with an emulator. You'll get a code that you can insert into the "hash key" facebook application.

I hope I've been helpful.