# Facebook Phonegap plugin - Able to log in (it seems) but cannot get access token

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am having trouble getting the phonegap facebook plugin to work. Did the following steps:

- I followed the automatic installation on https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin,
- added facebook-js-jdk and cdv-plugin-fb-connect to my platforms/android/assets/www folder
- replaced a line in the config.xml  < feature name="FacebookConnectPlugin" > to < feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" > (otherwise it never worked)

On startup, I get a "Cordova Facebook Connect plugin failed on init". Along with this, when I run my (copied and pasted) login function, in the logcat, a login object is returned with all of my information (name, correct userID, email, education and so on...), it says "User cancelled login or did not fully authorize". What's strange is that my getLoginStatus function seems to work properly, but doesn't return an access token. When it runs, it says that I am connected to Facebook, but in the logcat I see "cannot read property 'userID' of undefined".

I tried what was suggested by [java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo while logging using Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611969/java-lang-runtimeexception-failure-delivering-result-resultinfo-while-logging-u) (Don't keep activities on) but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated, I have been trying to get this to work for an embarrassingly long time now... My functions are below:

```
function testLogin(){
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log('Logged out.');
    });
    });
} else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
}, {scope: 'email'});
}

function getLoginStatus() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                                if (response.status == 'connected') {
                                alert('You are connected to Fb');
                                        var fbid = response.authResponse.userID;
                                        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                                        //console.log(response.authResponse.userID);
                                        //console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                                        alert(response);
                                } else {
                                alert('not connected to FB');
                                }
                                });
            }

function logout() {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                        alert('logged out');
});
}
```

Comment: I figured this out a while ago but maybe should post just to help out. I think it's an issue with the ConnectPlugin.java file, because once I replaced it with an older version (I think from February or March 2014 as opposed to April), I managed to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace has changed. Instead of using:

```
 FB.login(...
```

You should use:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(...
```

And replace **FB** with  **facebookConnectPlugin** elsewhere. 
Read the read me.md at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin, it might help you to keep everything up-to-date ;)

Comment: I read that and posted in one of the issues but I don't think a workaround was made to my knowledge at the time. They said that the FB method wont be deprecated for a while so I just kept it.

Comment: Now is just Facebook, not facebookConnectPlugin